# Issue with 'OOoDirect' subsystem loading in Alfresco 5.2

Tags: java, alfresco

I have an Alfresco 5.2.x with a solution(module AMPs), that provides many services to other external app, in this moment I need to use in this module this dependency for others features:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>es.gob.aapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>libreriaENI</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
    <type>jar</type>          
</dependency>
```

However, when I insert this in my file pom.xml an error and warning occurs on the starting of Alfresco System:

```
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |  2024-03-01 11:56:29,628  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default]
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |  2024-03-01 11:56:29,727  WARN  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ChildApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openOfficeStartupBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar!/alfresco/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/openoffice-transform-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'openOfficeStartupCommand' while setting bean property 'startupCommands' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openOfficeStartupCommand' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar!/alfresco/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/openoffice-transform-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
201707-ga-alfresco-1     | PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeCommandLine' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'commandsAndArguments'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |  2024-03-01 11:56:29,730  WARN  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default] failed
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openOfficeStartupBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar!/alfresco/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/openoffice-transform-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'openOfficeStartupCommand' while setting bean property 'startupCommands' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openOfficeStartupCommand' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar!/alfresco/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/openoffice-transform-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
201707-ga-alfresco-1     | PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeCommandLine' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'commandsAndArguments'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ApplicationContextState.start(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:824)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:1098)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:637)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
201707-ga-alfresco-1     | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openOfficeStartupCommand' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar!/alfresco/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/openoffice-transform-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
201707-ga-alfresco-1     | PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeCommandLine' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'commandsAndArguments'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

This error just appears when I do that, without ther my Alfresco starts correctly. Any idea about this issue?

I hope to remove those errors from my Alfresco start services and be able to use the dependency that I need correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the module `es.gob.aapp` you're trying to install is not compatible with your Alfresco version. You should talk to the es.gob team to request an update which supports your Alfresco version or you hire a consultant who is able to do the required code changes in that module.